# What does spooling mean in the context of JCache?

Tags: java, spool, spooler, jcache

From the [JCP page of JCache](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=107) :

> The JCACHE specification standardizes in process caching of Java
>   objects in a way that allows an efficient implementation, and removes
>   from the programmer the burden of implementing cache expiration,
>   mutual exclusion, **spooling**, and cache consistency.

What does `spooling` mean in this context ? Also how does spooling relate to caches ?

I can not relate the concept of [spooling as given in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spooling) to JCache which is a standard  for implementing caching .

Comment: why not? "simultaneous peripheral operations on-line" could definitely relate to a cache - any long running aynchronous operation on cache data is a spool

Comment: could you elaborate more on this. want to know.

Comment: In computerese, "spooling" is another term for FIFO queuing.